# Selecting line features by topology in QGIS (select dangles)

Tags: qgis, line, topology, select

I want to select line features by their relationship to their neighbouring line features.
To perform generalisation on the data set I need to select lines that:

- Do not intersect with their end point with other features
- OR
- Do not intersect with their start point with other features
- AND
- are below a certain length (let's say 100)

**I need to select *dangles* (line segments with one unconnected end (or start) point).**

So far, I have tried (updated):

```
(intersects(start_point($geometry), difference(collect($geometry),$geometry)) AND  disjoint(end_point($geometry), difference(collect($geometry),$geometry))) OR (intersects( end_point( $geometry ), difference(collect($geometry),$geometry)) AND disjoint(start_point($geometry), difference(collect($geometry),$geometry)))
```

The output is not what I am looking for though.
Some dangles don't get selected, and some line features that aren't dangles are selected.

How can I do this?

**Update regarding topology tools:** The tools "Topology Checker" and "Check Geometries" seem to have problems finding real dangles. Both tools target end or start points of line features that are definitly connected to other features (vertexes and segments).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck in the select by expression field. I can't wrap my head around how I can select features by their end or starting point topology.

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you tried so far?

Comment: this is my try:

intersects( start_point(  $geometry ),  [at]layer ) OR intersects( end_point(  $geometry ),  [at]layer )

I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: What is this `[at]layer`?

Comment: I tried to ask for intersections between the start_point of every line feature and the line features of the whole shapefile layer ([at]layer)

Comment: if the current feature is in the "at layer", it will always intersect that layer, because it's part of that layer and it intersects itself

Comment: true. how can I intersect with "everything else except the feature looked at"?

Comment: The geometry functions can't accept a whole layer, they need a single geometry as input. Use `collect($geometry)` instead of the non-existent `@layer` term you've been trying to use. This expression should give you "everything else except the feature looked at": `difference(collect($geometry),$geometry))`.

Comment: @Boschetto - Just a train of thought as but you could try running the GRASS tool `v.clean` and selecting the _rmdangle_ tool then set a threshold which you think is enough to remove the dangles in the layer. Then use the `Difference` tool with your original layer and the cleaned layer. Hopefully you'll be left with just dangles in a new layer which you could then add a new attribute field identifying these as dangles when you join/merge with the original layer or copy the original features into this new layer etc.

Answer (score 4):

The logic you can use is: if a linestring does not intersect with the endpoint or startpoint of another linestring, it has a dangle.

This logic can be written as:

```
aggregate(
layer:='your_layer',
aggregate:='count',
expression:=fid,
filter:=intersects($geometry, end_point(geometry(@parent)))) - 1 = 0
or 
aggregate(
layer:='your_layer',
aggregate:='count',
expression:=fid,
filter:=intersects($geometry, start_point(geometry(@parent)))) - 1 = 0
```

Change the values `your_layer` with the name of your lineslayer and `fid` with the name of your id-field

Because this query evaluates the amount of intersections a feature makes on his own layer, includes also the intersection with itself.  So we have substract the result with 1.