# Generating line features with "must not have dangles" constraint in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatialite, topology, v.clean

I am making line features in QGIS and sometimes, if I work inaccurate, they have dangels (loose ends). That is what I want to avoid.

There are ways to detect dangles **after** creating a feature (topology checker, check geometry, `v.clean` or in [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333802/selecting-line-features-by-topology-in-qgis-select-dangles)).

However, I would like to find a way that QGIS does not let me generate them in the first place. Every end point and every start point should be connected to another feature or to the line feature itself.

I know it is possible to implement constraints in the attribute form, but is it possible to implement such 'geometry constraints' from the beginning somehow? Maybe in a database (SpatiaLite or PostGIS)?

Comment: Perhaps a combination of snapping configuration and topological editing. Have a read through:  https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html

Comment: I am actually looking for a more 'solid' solution. In a database maybe.

Comment: No worries mate- was just an idea...

Comment: And by the way, if your requirements are more specific, perhaps you should add that information to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I updated the question.

Comment: How would you digitize the first line on a layer? Obviously it should make a closed loop, right?

Comment: @user30184 if you digitize thousands of lines, errors inevitably happen. Right?

Comment: I asked for getting more information about how you would like to build a growing linear network but you have actually already told that, by connecting both ends of the lines to existing lines, or to the new line itself. My workflow has been to snap to existing geometries within a tolerance and allow to create longer, not connected linestrings. I do also have such dead ends in the data that I map. With reasonable snapping distance short dangling lines are rare.